# Flutter & Redis client

Tags: php, flutter, redis

I have (Chat) Flutter mobile app which uses Lumen as backend. However, I want to cache some things and would like to use Redis for this purpose. Is there a way how Flutter app can speak with Redis? Should I install some package for this or make HTTP request for every caching?

My goal is to store last conversation message.

On backend side I can do something like this:

```
Redis::hSet('chat1', 'message', 'hello');
```

But I am not sure how this is going to affect performance... Therefore it would be better to have Redis client on Frontend side (Flutter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/redis 
This package is `Redis` client for `Dart`

code snippet

```
import 'package:redis/redis.dart';
...
RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
conn.connect('localhost',6379).then((Command command){
    command.send_object(["SET","key","0"]).then((var response)
        print(response);
    )
}
```